# C# MVVM, wait for some events to fire and keep on updating the UI

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mvvm, async-await, mahapps.metro

I'm building a MMVMLight application which at some point have to upload files to an azure storage account and then in case of success will update some data in a SQL server.

My method works this way :

```
public ICommand UploadCICommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_UploadCICommand == null)
            {
                _UploadCICommand = new RelayCommand(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ProgressDialogController controller;

                        // next upload CI
                        MetroDialogSettings dialogSettings = new MetroDialogSettings { AnimateHide = false, AnimateShow = true };
                        if ((await dialogCoordinator.ShowMessageAsync(this, "Confirm", $"Are you sure want to upload {appName} ?", MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative, (new MetroDialogSettings { AnimateHide = false, AnimateShow = true })) == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative))
                        {
                            controller = await dialogCoordinator.ShowProgressAsync(this, "Please Wait...", string.Empty, false, (new MetroDialogSettings { AnimateHide = false, AnimateShow = false }));

                            controller.SetMessage($"Uploading content");

                            CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(sasUri));

                            ICloudBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(zipFile);

                            BlobTransfer blobTransfer = new BlobTransfer();
                            blobTransfer.TransferCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(blobTransfer_TransferCompleted);
                            blobTransfer.TransferProgressChanged += new EventHandler<BlobTransfer.BlobTransferProgressChangedEventArgs>(blobTransfer_TransferProgressChanged);

                            blobTransfer.UploadBlobAsync(blob, zipFile);

                            //And then, the code to update database....
                          }
                     }
              }
          }
      }
 }

void blobTransfer_TransferProgressChanged(object sender, BlobTransfer.BlobTransferProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var SetDebugBreakPointIfNeededHere = 1;

        //Main stuff to do
        // Parent object of sender -> controller.SetProgress(e.ProgressPercentage); 

        // Other information that would be cool to show
        //Speed = (e.Speed / 1024 / 1024).ToString("N0");
        //TimeRemaining = e.TimeRemaining.ToString();
        //Progress = e.ProgressPercentage;
        //SizeDowloaded = (e.BytesSent / 1024 / 1024).ToString("N0");
    }

    void blobTransfer_TransferCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var SetDebugBreakPointIfNeededHere = 1;
        //EndTime = System.DateTime.Now;
        //if (e.Cancelled)
        //{
        //    Log cancel and try preventing main function to continue
        //}
        //else if (e.Error != null)
        //{
        //    Log failure and try preventing main function to continue
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    Speed = ((((BlobSize) / 1024 / 1024) / (EndTime - StartTime).TotalSeconds)).ToString("N0");
        //    Let the caller method continue
        //}
    }
```

What I would like to achieve is :

- Wait TransferCompleted event to be triggered before if go to the update DB part
- And while I'm waiting the end of the upload to update the progressbar by calling "controller.SetProgress();" in my TransferProgressChanged but in this method I don't have access to the controller object.

So far what I have thought about is

- For point 1 : Set my "DB update code" in the blobTransfer_TransferCompleted method to be sure it's not get called until the event is triggered
- For point two : As the sender of the progress changed event is my BlobTransfer object I still don't know how to call the set progress method of my dialog. I was maybe thinking about using reflexion to get the parent object of my sender and try to update the value here.

What I'm quite sure of is that both of my ideas are not smart but right now I cannot figure out a clever way to do this.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a Task based async API for the blobs?  This seems so 2010.

Comment: 2013 to be exact ! The code comes from here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2013/03/05/asynchronous-parallel-blob-transfers-with-progress-change-notification-2-0/ But from what I've found on the net, there is Nothing newer that allow an async upload or download of blob in Azure with progress update and parallel transfer

Comment: OK, yes, and nobody bothered to implement something with IProgress.

Comment: Your problem is that  `//And then, the code to update database...` will have to move to the completed event. And in order to keep yourself honest, remove that `async`  from `async () =>`. It is misleading.

Comment: Correction I finally found a new libraryMicrosoft Azure Storage Data Movement Library which seems to do the trick !

Comment: OK, you could post a self-answer if that's working out

Comment: Yep, trying to finish my method to post the code sample.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the Microsoft Azure Storage Data Movement Library which works in a more modern way :

```
CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(sasUri));

                            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(Path.GetFileName(zipFile));

                            // Setup the number of the concurrent operations
                            TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 64;

                            // Setup the transfer context and track the upoload progress
                            SingleTransferContext context = new SingleTransferContext();

                            context.ProgressHandler = new Progress<TransferStatus>((progress) =>
                            {
                                int percentage = (int)Math.Round((double)((double)progress.BytesTransferred / (double)zipFileInfo.Length * 100));
                                //controller.SetProgress(percentage);
                                controller.SetMessage($"Uploading content {percentage}%");
                            });

                            context.ShouldOverwriteCallbackAsync = new ShouldOverwriteCallbackAsync(ShouldTransferCallback);

                            // Upload a local blob
                            await TransferManager.UploadAsync(
                                zipFile, blob, null, context, CancellationToken.None);
```

with ShouldTransferCallback always returning true as I want to overwrite blobs each time.

```
private async Task<bool> ShouldTransferCallback(object source, object dest)
    {
        return true;
    }
```